# doctrine 1.2 - doctrine collection auto group by id

Tags: collections, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have a sql view with multiple tables joined with union all. The view has a collumn id which is the primary key for each record (which can came from different tables).

The problem ism becuase the view results from a union, there might be more than one row with the same id.
In this cases Doctrine_Collection seems to automaticly group all the records by the id collumn making some records to disapear.
Is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to combine those records in a union, one way around that problem is to alias the id field for each subquery or table so that the id fields don't get combined.